# How to fix the following group_send communication issue in Django

Tags: django

I want to create a  websocket which will send a group message, but the following code does not seem to be working.

The function that must be called is not being called, and wrapping it in a `async_to_sync`, results in a error.
Here is the code:

```
    async def receive(self, text_data):
        # Store the message in the database
        message = json.loads(text_data)
        name = message['name']
        text = message['message']
        document = {'name': name, 'message': text}
        # Send the message to all connected clients
        # await self.send(text_data=json.dumps(message))
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type':'chat_message',
                'message':message
            }
        )
        collection.update_one(
            {},
            {'$push': {'text': document}}
        )

    async def chat_message(self, event):
        # Send the message to all connected clients
        print("Message sent to group")
        message = event['message']
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({'type':'chat','message': message}))
```

However when I use `await self.send(text_data=json.dumps(message))` It does work, only the group_send is not working.
Below is the frontend(SvelteKit) code if needed:

````
        socket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/chat");
        socket.addEventListener("open", () => {
            console.log("Connection is successful!");
        });
        socket.onmessage = (e) => {
            const message = JSON.parse`your text`(e.data);
            console.log("Received message:", message);
            messages = [...messages, message];
        };
    });```
````